# Android: How to make a specific SharedPreference reset itself after the system reboots?

Tags: android

I have a SharedPreference that I need to reset itself to its initial value after the phone reboots... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the [BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) broadcast action, and reset the preference from your receiver.